# What is causing the buffer overrun error in below code

Tags: vector, heap-corruption, address-sanitizer

Unable to figure out what is causing the buffer overflow in below code. I reckon it has to do with the vector but I am guarding against out of bounds access. Is there anything else that could be causing the overflow?

```
class Solution {
public:
    bool canPartition(vector<int>& nums) {
        int sum = 0;
        bool canPartition = true;
        vector<vector<int>> dp(nums.size(), vector<int>(sum / 2 + 1, -1));
        sum = accumulate(nums.begin(),nums.end(),0);
        if (sum % 2 != 0)
        {
            canPartition = false;
        }
        if (true == canPartition)
        {
            canPartition = canPartitionRecursive(nums, 0, sum/2, dp);
        }
        return canPartition;
    }
    bool canPartitionRecursive(vector<int>& nums, int index, int sum, 
                               vector<vector<int>>& dp)
    {
        if (sum == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (index >= nums.size() || sum < 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (dp[index][sum] != -1)
        {
            if (true == canPartitionRecursive(nums, index+1, sum - nums[index],dp))
            {
                dp[index][sum] = 1;
                return true;
            }
            dp[index][sum] = canPartitionRecursive(nums, index + 1, sum, dp);
        }
        return dp[index][sum] = 1? true:false;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a transpositional error (all subvector will have size 1):

```
int sum = 0;
vector<vector<int>> dp(nums.size(), vector<int>(sum / 2 + 1, -1));
sum = accumulate(nums.begin(),nums.end(),0);
```

Perhaps calculation of `sum` should be moved before `dp` initialization?